# Docker compose file format and configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops

I have a docker compose file that is transferred from previous vendor and this is something like that

```
api-service:
  image: ${IMAGE}
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  environment:
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: ${PROFILE}

  log_driver: awslogs
```

When I try to build with this file, it cannot be built by compose. The error message is `(root) Additional property api-service is not allowed".` I think this file is not in correct format for docker compose. I want to know that is there any configuration is need to make that file work or is there some kind of docker feature that can combine partial docker compose file like that?

I gonna add more information. Currently I have 2 files like this under different service names and my idea is that there must be a parent docker compose file that will include/import those 2 files to form a fully working docker compose file. I already read docker compose documentation for that kind of feature and haven't found anything that close to something like this.

Comment: "*it cannot be built by compose*" Pretty sure, `docker-compose` presents you with some kind of error. Mind to share that error?

Comment: Yes. It said ``(root) Additional property api-service is not allowed".``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a "version 1" Compose file.  This was the first version of the Compose YAML file format.  It just contains the list of service definitions at the top level; it does not have a `version:` tag or a `services:` block header; and it has no way to declare `networks:` or `volumes:`.

There are also two versions of the Compose tool itself.  As of June 2023 Docker discontinued support for the older (Python-based) version.  If you can run `docker compose` with a space, you have the newer version.  However, the Compose tool version 2 doesn't support Compose file version 1.

If you have the newer Compose tool, the fastest path to get something close to working is to indent the entire file by two spaces, and then add `services:` as a first line above it.

```yaml
services:
  api-service:
    ...
```

If you want to keep compatibility with the older Compose tool, you will also need a `version: '2.4'` or `version: '3.8'` line, typically at the very top of the file.

In all of these file formats, the way to specify the logging driver has changed.  The driver setting is under a [`logging:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#logging) block (link to Compose file v3 docs; same setting in Compose file v2 and Compose Specification).

So I might translate this file to

```yaml
version: '3.8'  # ignored by Compose v2; specifies file format in Compose v1
services:       # add, indent following lines
  api-service:
    image: ${IMAGE}
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: ${PROFILE}
    logging:    # change from log_driver
      driver: awslogs
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker compose files must have the two top-level keys `version` and `services`. `version` is a string and `services` is a dict of all services. You snippet looks like a single service definition.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

A minimal compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    image: hello-world
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I already familiar with the basic docker compose file format. That thing is I was wondering is there any docker compose feature that can combine two or more partial docker compose file? Currently I have 3 files in that format and it's not making any sense just only with partial format. My idea is like there is main docker compose file that will include these partial files to make a fully working docker compose file.

Comment: @uranium235 I'm not aware of such a feature. You could ask whoever provided you with these files how you are supposed to run them